# How to use create-react-app to develop multiple pages?

Tags: reactjs

When creating an app with create-react-app,there is only one index.html,does that means React can only handle one SPA at a time? What if I want to develop multiple pages? Should I create another SPA with create-react-app and then put them together after building each of them?

Comment: You're right, there is no official way to develop multiple pages by create-react-app. But you can find some solutions in this issue –  https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1084

Comment: Just use react-router.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

[Parceljs](https://parceljs.org/) can do that. [here is docs.](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html#multiple-entry-files)

You can use Parcel instead of Webpack (which being used in create-react-app) and it provide you zero config environment to develop web apps (using react or anything else).

---

Having multiple pages (instead of SPA) is not what most React environments had in mind [before - see update above].

You can have different page URL's using react-router or similar client side routing solutions.

If the concern is bundle size, there are solutions using webpack or parcel to lazy load each bundle whenever they needed or cache bundle (using service workers) and so on (Tree shaking, ...). (check [Code Splitting in React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html))

Other concern I might have in my brain is SEO, in this case you may find Isomorphic app (react server side rendering) useful which initialize first view of requested URL HTML and sends it to client, then client will load react and react will take control of UI. This will help Google (or other search engines) find your URLs fast and user experience in transitions between pages will remain seamless.

Comment: "default usage of react for single page applications"
Can you share the documentation that outlines the default usages of react?

React is a UI framework, a library so to speak. Not a full fledged web framework. React does not care about single page or multi page applications.

Comment: @Programmatic you are right, my answer was opinionated, check the updated answer. Thank you.