# react-create-app use generated css in other html file

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack

I'm using `react-create-app` for creating a single page application. Now I have to create a legal page with static text, which I don't want to be part of the main application.

Is there a way to create another `.html` file in the public folder and reference the generated css file to use the same style sheet?

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use create-react-app to develop multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998283/how-to-use-create-react-app-to-develop-multiple-pages)